# Compaq 6910p touchpad scrolling stopped working after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, touchpad, scrolling

A few people seem to have this problem, but I didn't find any solutions.

Removing and re-adding psmouse with modprobe doesn't help.

Two-finger scrolling is enabled in settings.

xinput shows this (not sure what it should show for a working touchpad):

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```